# Streaming a .js.erb response

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In this scenario, when the user submits his form,
the `$("body .my-flash-div")` div should first show

```
Generating report
```

then after a few seconds

```
Sql executing
```

so on and so forth.

My issue is that the end user is shown the results at once, and not in a step by step manner. Here's my setup:

```
End users want to download reports
Report generation is a multi step process, takes 5-10 seconds.
Step 1 user does GET /users_report/new
There's a form there, user enters email address, submits
And it's handled by

class UsersReportController < ApplicationController
    def create
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end


# app/views/users_report/create.js.erb
$("body .my-flash-div").html("Generating report");
<% Namespace::gen_report_step_1 %>
<% sleep 1 %>
$("body .my-flash-div").html("Sql executing");
<% Namespace::gen_report_step_2 %>
<% sleep 1 %>
$("body .my-flash-div").html("Post processing");
<% Namespace::gen_report_step_3 %>
<% sleep 1 %>
$("body .my-flash-div").html("gzip execute");
<% Namespace::gen_report_step_4 %>
<% sleep 1 %>
$("body .my-flash-div").html("Emailing "+params[:email]);
```

Can can I make this work, or should I look at actionable for this, if so how.

Comment: You can use [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) or [jQuery.delay](https://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Comment: I added some sleep 1 calls to illustrate why setTimeout and .delay might not be appropriate

Comment: Yeah if you want to perform a bunch of tasks that might take time and have the client subscribe for updates you´ll want to use ActionCable. Otherwise the response is sent once the view is rendered in entirety.

Comment: can ActionCable::Live be used?

Comment: Yes, but this is a far too broad subject for StackOverflow. There are plenty of ActiomCable tutorials on the web.

Comment: trying to understand your last comment.   per my understanding ActionController::Live != ActionCable
. they are totally unrelated concepts.

Answer (score 0):

To do something like this I used the Thread technique mentioned at
`https://solidfoundationwebdev.com/blog/posts/how-to-perform-some-task-after-view-render-using-threads-in-rails`.
Also helpful was this doc about how to use ActionCable `https://github.com/wintermeyer/rails-5.2-book/blob/master/action-cable.adoc`

```
# in controller
def create
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
  Thread.new do
    send_report(params[:email], "web_notifications_#{params[:async_response_guid]}")
    Thread.exit
  end
end


# inside send_report() method
...
ActionCable.server.broadcast(logger, msg: "Generating.")
...

# inside app/views/users_report/_form.html.erb
<% async_response_guid ||= SecureRandom.hex[0..6] %>

<script>
(function() {
    App.room = App.cable.subscriptions.create({
        channel: "WebNotificationsChannel",
        room: "<%= async_response_guid %>"
    }, {
        received: function(data) {
            $(".output-<%=async_response_guid%>").html(data.msg);
            return console.log("here1 " + data.msg);
        }
    });

}).call(this);
</script>
<span class="badge badge-pill badge-light form-flash output-<%=async_response_guid%>"></span>
```